# How do I retrieve devices by operating system

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to use objectfilter to retrieve only devices with the specific operating systems. I have tried elements operatingSystemReferenceCode and referenceCode in the objectfilter, but devices are returned with other operating systems.

Here is the https request I am using.

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?resultLimit=0,100&objectMask=mask[datacenter,status,globalIdentifier,primaryBackendIpAddress,billingItem.categoryCode,billingItem.description,billingItem.createDate,billingItem.orderItem.preset,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.email,users.username,users.email,users.userStatus,operatingSystemReferenceCode,softwareComponents.passwords,operatingSystem,hourlyBillingFlag,localDiskFlag,managedResourceFlag,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,powerState,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.name,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.id,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.blockDevices,blockDevices.diskImage,networkVlans,primaryBackendNetworkComponent,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions,consoleIpAddressRecord.type,consoleIpAddressRecord.port,consoleIpAddressRecord.ipAddress.ipAddress,userDataCount,userData]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"operatingSystemReferenceCode":{"operation":"^=DEBIAN_7_64"}}}

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,operatingSystem[id,softwareDescription[id,productItems]]]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"operatingSystem":{"softwareDescription":{"productItems":{"keyName":{"operation":"OS_WINDOWS_2012_R2_FULL_STD_64_BIT"}}}}}}
```

OS_WINDOWS_2012_R2_FULL_STD_64_BIT is the operationSystem keyName.

For obtaining the keyName you should use:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[categories[categoryCode],keyName]]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"os"}}}}
```

Choose the operationSystem keyName which wants to filter

I hope it helps